# Snooze notification programmatically on NON OREO devices

Tags: android, android-notifications, notification-listener

in my app i have a service which needs to run in background. I started it in foreground mode which requies a notification to work. I need to implement a feature which a user can snooze the notification related to this service. I used NotificationListenerService in which there is a method called snoozeNotification. But this method requies api 26 and works only on oreo devices. For non oreo devices, the only solution that i thought is to notify the user that he can snooze all the notifications of the app from the settings. But this solution snoozes other notifications that need to be visible. Do you have any other solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to listen  swipe to dismiss event?

Answer (score -1):

`DeleteIntent`: is a `PendingIntent` object that can be associated with a notification and gets fired when the notification gets deleted, ether by :

User specific action
User Delete all the notifications.
You can set the Pending Intent to a`BroadcastReceiver` and then perform any action you want.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
  Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this):
 ..... code for your notification
  builder.setDeleteIntent(pendingIntent);
```

And in other places, to listen whenever you Notification was closed/deleted.

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             .... code to handle cancel
         }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Tomorrow i will try your solution